# sql aggregate case query

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have the one line query to get the sum of red, yellow, green and cyan items individually for every hour over the past 24 hours.  The query returns the correct result.  But is it possible to simplify it?  Thanks in advance.

```
Set statistics io on;
DECLARE @currentTimeInMs bigint = 398244649728; -- input parameter
DECLARE @oneHourInMs bigint = 3600000; -- 1 hour = 60 mins = 3600 secs = 3600000 msecs
DECLARE @h24 bigint = @currentTimeInMs

DECLARE @h00 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 24)
DECLARE @h01 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 23)
DECLARE @h02 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 22)
DECLARE @h03 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 21)
DECLARE @h04 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 20)
DECLARE @h05 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 19)
DECLARE @h06 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 18)
DECLARE @h07 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 17)
DECLARE @h08 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 16)
DECLARE @h09 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 15)
DECLARE @h10 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 14)
DECLARE @h11 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 13)
DECLARE @h12 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 12)
DECLARE @h13 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 11)
DECLARE @h14 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 10)
DECLARE @h15 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 9)
DECLARE @h16 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 8)
DECLARE @h17 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 7)
DECLARE @h18 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 6)
DECLARE @h19 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 5)
DECLARE @h20 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 4)
DECLARE @h21 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 3)
DECLARE @h22 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 2)
DECLARE @h23 bigint = @h24 - (@oneHourInMs * 1)


SELECT @currentTimeInMs AS CurrentTimeInMs,
-- H00
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h00 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h01 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H00Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h00 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h01 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H00Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h00 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h01 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H00Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h00 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h01 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H00Cyan',
-- H01
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h01 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h02 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H01Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h01 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h02 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H01Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h01 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h02 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H01Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h01 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h02 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H01Cyan',
-- H02
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h02 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h03 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H02Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h02 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h03 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H02Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h02 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h03 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H02Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h02 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h03 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H02Cyan',
-- H03
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h03 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h04 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H03Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h03 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h04 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H03Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h03 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h04 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H03Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h03 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h04 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H03Cyan',
-- H04
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h04 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h05 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H04Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h04 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h05 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H04Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h04 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h05 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H04Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h04 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h05 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H04Cyan',
-- H05
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h05 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h06 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H05Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h05 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h06 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H05Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h05 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h06 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H05Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h05 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h06 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H05Cyan',
-- H06
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h06 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h07 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H06Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h06 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h07 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H06Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h06 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h07 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H06Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h06 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h07 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H06Cyan',
-- H07
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h07 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h08 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H07Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h07 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h08 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H07Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h07 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h08 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H07Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h07 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h08 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H07Cyan',
-- H08
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h08 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h09 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H08Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h08 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h09 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H08Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h08 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h09 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H08Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h08 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h09 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H08Cyan',
-- H09
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h09 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h10 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H09Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h09 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h10 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H09Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h09 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h10 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H09Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h09 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h10 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H09Cyan',
-- H10
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h10 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h11 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H10Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h10 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h11 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H10Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h10 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h11 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H10Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h10 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h11 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H10Cyan',
-- H11
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h11 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h12 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H11Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h11 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h12 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H11Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h11 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h12 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H11Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h11 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h12 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H11Cyan',
-- H12
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h12 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h13 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H12Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h12 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h13 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H12Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h12 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h13 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H12Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h12 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h13 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H12Cyan',
-- H13
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h13 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h14 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H13Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h13 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h14 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H13Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h13 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h14 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H13Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h13 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h14 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H13Cyan',
-- H14
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h14 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h15 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H14Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h14 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h15 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H14Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h14 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h15 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H14Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h14 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h15 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H14Cyan',
-- H15
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h15 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h16 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H15Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h15 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h16 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H15Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h15 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h16 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H15Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h15 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h16 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H15Cyan',
-- H16
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h16 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h17 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H16Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h16 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h17 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H16Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h16 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h17 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H16Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h16 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h17 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H16Cyan',
-- H17
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h17 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h18 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H17Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h17 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h18 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H17Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h17 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h18 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H17Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h17 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h18 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H17Cyan',
-- H18
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h18 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h19 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H18Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h18 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h19 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H18Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h18 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h19 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H18Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h18 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h19 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H18Cyan',
-- H19
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h19 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h20 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H19Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h19 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h20 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H19Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h19 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h20 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H19Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h19 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h20 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H19Cyan',
-- H20
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h20 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h21 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H20Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h20 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h21 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H20Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h20 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h21 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H20Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h20 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h21 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H20Cyan',
-- H21
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h21 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h22 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H21Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h21 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h22 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H21Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h21 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h22 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H21Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h21 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h22 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H21Cyan',
-- H22
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h22 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h23 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H22Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h22 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h23 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H22Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h22 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h23 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H22Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h22 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h23 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H22Cyan',
-- H23
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h23 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h24 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H23Red',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h23 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h24 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x200)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H23Yellow',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h23 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h24 AND Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x100)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H23Green',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @h23 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h24 AND Kind=1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS 'H23Cyan'   

FROM Alert A
WHERE A.AnnounceStartTime BETWEEN @h00 AND @h24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can simplify it.  You can create flags for each element, and then multiply them together:

```
select sum(isHH00*isRed) as HH00Red,
       sum(isHH00*isYellow) as HH00Yellow,
       . . .
from (select a.*,
             (case when Kind=0 AND (Severity=0x400) then 1 else 0 end) as IsRed,
             . . .
             (case when @h00 <= AnnounceStartTime AND AnnounceStartTime < @h01
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as isHH00,
             . . .
      from Alert a
     ) a
where . . .
```

Your other alternative is to group the query by doing:

```
select datepart(hh, AnnounceStartTime), kind, Severity, count(*) as cnt
from Alert a
group by datepart(hh, AnnounceStartTime), kind, Severity
```

Then pivot this into the data you need, using either the PIVOT statement or another tool such as Excel.

Comment: Both solutions worked! The first query using flags is creative. However, after I completed implementing, the query is quite long.  The second solution is very short.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start off by creating a temporary summary table:

```
declare
  @one_hour_in_ms    int      ,
  @dtNow             datetime ,
  @@dtNowLess24Hours datetime

set @one_hour_in_ms   = 60 * 60 * 1000
 set @dtNow            = current_timestamp        -- current date and time
 set @dtNowLess24Hours = dateadd(hour,-24,@dtNow)

create table #work
(
  period_id int not null primary key clustered ,
  red       int not null ,
  yellow    int not null ,
  green     int not null ,
  cyan      int not null ,
)

insert #work ( period_id , red , yellow , green , cyan )
select period_id = datediff(ms,@startofPeriod,a.AnnounceStartTime) / @one_hour_in_ms , -- creates period id with the domain 0-23 indicating the hour offset within the reporting period
       red       = sum( case when a.Kind = 0 and a.Severity = 0x400 then 1 else 0 end ) ,
       yellow    = sum( case when a.Kind = 0 and a.Severity = 0x200 then 1 else 0 end ) ,
       green     = sum( case when a.Kind = 0 and a.Severity = 0x100 then 1 else 0 end ) ,
       cyan      = sum( case when a.Kind = 1                        then 1 else 0 end )
from Alert a
where a.AnnounceStartTime >= @startOfPeriod
  and a.AnnounceStartTime <  @dtNow
group by datediff(ms,@startofPeriod,a.AnnounceStartTime) / @one_hour_in_ms
```

The above creates a temporary table with up to 24 rows, one for each hour in the 24-hour reporting period. Naturally, if no data was recorded for the period, no row will be generated.

You could, if that is sufficient, just return that as a multi-row result set and let the client rotate the rows into columns. Otherwise, you need to do a *table rotation*. An implementation agnostic way to do that, one that doesn't depend on `pivot`, is to do this:

```
select dtFrom  = @dtNowLess24Hours ,
       dtThru  = @dtNow            ,
       H00_Red = sum( p00.red ) , H00_Yellow = sum( p00.yellow ) , H00_Green = sum( p00.green ) , H00_Cyan = sum( p00.cyan ) ,
       H01_Red = sum( p01.red ) , H01_Yellow = sum( p01.yellow ) , H01_Green = sum( p01.green ) , H01_Cyan = sum( p01.cyan ) ,
       ...
       H23_Red = sum( p23.red ) , H23_Yellow = sum( p23.yellow ) , H23_Green = sum( p23.green ) , H23_Cyan = sum( p23.cyan )
from       ( select * from #work where period_id = 0  ) p00
cross join ( select * from #work where period_id = 1  ) p01
...
cross join ( select * from #work where period_id = 23 ) p23
```

If your system supports `pivot`, then the whole process is much simpler.